# How to know what percent of document that I read in Safari?

Tags: safari, macos

When using Safari to read documentation, how do I know how much do I read or much much more is left to read just like I do with editors?

[image]

There seems to be no indicator in Safari for that purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you initiate a scroll a little bit either up or down a scrollbar will appear in Safari letting you know where you are in the document unless it has been disabled by code in the website.

You could use a "User Style Sheet" to have the scrollbar always appear: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/ht/htcssusersafari.htm

Or you can do it the easiest way and go to "System Preferences > General" and choose "Show Scrollbars > Always".

[image]

Comment: If your Mac has a multi-touch trackpad and you're running Mountain Lion, you can also tap the trackpad with two fingers to make the scrollbar appear; no need to actually scroll up or down.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the scrollbar?  It's there just hard to see. Next to the words directory and path in the enlargement below. Becomes more visible when you hover that margin of the window.

You can stop auto hiding this in system pref->general->show scroll bars = always. 
[image: enlarged section of safari screenshot]